# Doctrine query builder remove objects created x days ago

Tags: symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I'm trying to come up with a query to use to remove objects in a specfic table that were created `$xDaysAgo` days ago from today (today's date is created using a new dateTime object).

So in my database i would have

```
id | created_at | name

5  | 2020-01-01 12:00:00 | test
6  | 2020-04-09 15:00:00 | test1
7  | 2020-04-11 15:00:00 | test2
```

And then i choose the `$xDaysAgo` to be `5` then my method `removeObject($xDaysAgo)` would should only delete the objects with id `6` and `7` (as today is the 11th). 
I was told that using queryBuilder you can just order the objects and delete the ones satisfying the criteria directly. I however couldn't find a single example demonstrating this. I managed to implement a smiliar functionality but not quite what i'm looking for. I have this now to delete an array of objects but it doesn't take the date into account:

```
    public function removeObject(array $objectIds)
    {
        $qb = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->getConnection()
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->delete('someTable');
        $qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('id', $objectIds));
        $qb->execute();
    }
```

Which seems to be working fine. I can't seem to edit this to achieve what i really want though. Any help will be appreciated!

my final method should be something like this (this is ofc a few of the details that should be changed and not by anyway a working piece of code):

```
    public function removeObject(int $xDaysAgo)
    {
        $qb = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->getConnection()
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->delete('someTable');
        //order them using created_at and then delete those seems better than looping throw all of them??
        $qb->add('orderBy', $qb->expr()->in('created_at', $xDaysAgo));
        $qb->execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand your question.

You want to delete entities created exactly x days before today? 
If this is what you want, you could directly delete entities created between the (x)th and (x+1)th days.

```php
  $begin = new DateTimeImmutable('-5 days');
  $end = new DateTimeImmutable('-6 days');

  //If you want to fix a day, you should use:
  //$begin = (new DateTime('-5 days'))->setTime(0,0,0);
  //$end = (new DateTime('-5 days'))->setTime(23,59,59);

  $qb = $this->getEntityManager()
     ->getConnection()
     ->createQueryBuilder()
     ->delete('someTable')
     ->where('createdAt between :end and :begin')
     ->setParameter('begin', $begin)
     ->setParameter('end', $end);
```

Comment: I tried my best to provide explanation of what i wanted but sometimes i can do a bad job at it, sorry xD. But yeah i would like to delete all entities that were created exactly x days before today. Let me check your soltuion out and will return back to you in a sec

Comment: An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM someTable WHERE created_at between ? and ?' with params [{"date":"2020-04-11 21:08:27.701372","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Amsterdam"}, {"date":"2020-04-06 21:08:27.048251","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Amsterdam"}]:

Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTimeImmutable could not be converted to string

When i try do this:

        `$begin = new DateTimeImmutable('-' . $period . ' days');
        $end = new DateTimeImmutable('now');`

Comment: so the times seems to be correct but something else is going wrong?

Comment: You should perhaps convert manually your object into a string in the `setParameter` method. `$begin->format(DateTimeInterface::ISO_8601);` I'm not fluent with Mysql, so I don't know which is the better format.

Comment: Achieved the same doing `$begin->format('c');`  from https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php but still the same error :(